# Enhanced for loop empty check optimization

Tags: java, for-loop

I know with java one shouldn't bother with things like this but I just can't resist, which is the faster?:

```
ArrayList <Integer> keke = new ArrayList();
ArrayList <Integer> kuku = new ArrayList();
if(!keke.isEmpty()){
    for(Integer num : keke){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}

//or just:

for(Integer num : kuku){
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

The enhanced for loop does an empty check before it starts to do anything right? So using an enclosing if(empty) is totally useless?

Comment: Yes, it's redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The enhanced for loop does an empty check before it starts to do anything right?

No, I wouldn't expect it to. I'd expect it to just create the iterator, which then won't find anything. That's what [JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) describes, anyway:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>       {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
>           (TargetType) #i.next();
>       Statement
> }
> ```

The body of the loop will never be executed. Yes, it may create an extraneous object (the iterator) but in 99.99% of cases I'd expect that not to be a *significant* performance hit.
(As noted, the `iterator()` method may return a singleton empty iterator to avoid this...)

If you have *evidence* that in your specific application, this gets hit very, very frequently when the collection is empty, and that all the extra iterators are causing an issue, *then* it's fair to micro-optimize. But I wouldn't even think about doing it before you have concrete performance figures in a realistic context.

Comment: The iterator may even not cost anything; depending on the collection implementation iterated it may return you a shared instance (Collections.emptyIterator()).

Answer (score 3):

It's like writing:

```
for(Iterator<Integer> itr = kuku.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
   ...
}
```

And as you can see, it's redundant to check if it's empty since `hasNext` will be `false` and the loop won't be executed.